# How to insert part name in header (without titlesec)

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, parts

I need to get part name to insert it in some special pages (parts beginning pages), without using `\titlesec`package, but I haven't been able to get it until the moment. I tried defining a special pagestyle, but it didn't work.

This is test code I was working on:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{minitoc}

%Define pagestyle
\fancyhf{}% Clear all headers/footers
\fancyhead[L]{Left header}\fancyhead[C]{Centre header}\fancyhead[R]{Right header}
\fancyfoot[L]{Left footer}\fancyfoot[C]{Centre footer}\fancyfoot[R]{Right footer}
\pagestyle{fancy}


%Define especial pagestyle
\fancypagestyle{especial}{
\fancyhead[R]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
}

%Trying to include part name in headers (doesn't work)
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\part{%
\if@openright
\cleardoublepage
\else
\clearpage
\fi
\thispagestyle{especial}%
\if@twocolumn
\onecolumn
\@tempswatrue
\else
\@tempswafalse
\fi
\null\vfil
\secdef\@part\@spart}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\doparttoc
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{especial}    
\part{part 1}
\section{section 1}
\part{part 2}
\section{section 3}

\end{document}
```

[image]
Do someone get any idea how to do it?

Comment: `\markboth{#1}{#1}`? I am not sure i completely understand the question.

Comment: I just updated the post in order to do it clearer. I wouldn't know how to use this "\markboth{#1}{#1}" exactly in my code.

Comment: `\fancyhead[R]{#1}` in the definition of the part? Do you really think the reader will need this kind of information?

Comment: I tried but it didn't work me. That's in order to apply a pagestyle to initial part page.

Comment: AFAIK sectioning commands like part or chapter creates a new page and issue at `\thisppagestyle{empty}`. Hence of you really want to break this use, you would have to r patch the part command ( with \patchcmd or \appto from etoolbox, or redefine the \part command with \renewcommand) In both cases you would have to add either the standard \markboth command as suggested by @Johannes_B, or an equivalent defined with  fancyhdr.

Comment: I used `\renewcommand`, but I don´t know how to add that modification. Maybe a piece of code would be useful.